# How to find, for a temp. equation, Maxmum valus of position and time?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have to find the position `x` and the time `t` for which the temperature is a maximum. I have a function `T245[x_, y_, t_, b_, l_, d_, tau_]` and I want to know the maximum value with given `y_(=0)`, `b`, `l`,`d`, `tau`.
Sorry for any error but I'm a newbie.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Have you tried [Maximize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html)?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't works. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Ok, sorry. In general he replies with   NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand -(Erfc[ecc.] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,0.0005},{0.,0.000707107}}. My function is a subtraction of integrals containing complementary error functions

Comment: @LorenzoF It would be helpful if you could include the expression for `T245` in your question. Clearly it seems to include some integrals, since the `NIntegrate` error, but it would be hard to say more without seeing the code. Perhaps you could try re-defining the `T245` function to accept only numerical input, i.e. `T245[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, .... <and all the others similarly]`.

Comment: `T245[x_,y_,t_,b_,l_,d_,tau_]:=a * Sqrt(1+m^2) * NIntegrate[Erfc[Sqrt((x-alfa)^2+(y-beta)^2+(z-(m * alfa-d))^2)/Sqrt(4* t)]/Sqrt((x-alfa)^2+(y-beta)^2+(z-(m * alfa-d))^2)-Erfc[Sqrt((x-alfa)^2+(y-beta)^2+(z-(m * alfa-d))^2)/Sqrt(4 * (t-tau))]/Sqrt((x-alfa)^2+(y-beta)^2+(z-(m * alfa-d))^2), {beta,-b/2,b/2},{alfa,0,l}]` This is the expression for T245.